# D3js - Paths stuck in top left of browser window - how do I centralize them?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm looking to build a radial chart visualisation that can be positioned on my page nicely with x and y co-ordinated or in the centre of the div.

It was working fine, until I added in scaling animations on the svg path elements. Now my whole radial chart is packed into the top left hand corner and I can't get it out.

Can you help? Thanks so much.

```js
const svg = d3
  .select("#radial-chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);


const handleMouseOver = (d, i, n) => {
  svg.selectAll("path").transition().duration(300).style("opacity", 0.35);

  d3.select(n[i]).transition().duration(300).style("opacity", 0.35);
};

const handleMouseOut = (d, i, n) => {
  svg
    .selectAll("path")
    .transition()
    .duration(300)
    .style("opacity", 0.35)
    .style("stroke-width", 0);
};

const handleClick = (d, i, n) => {
  if (
    $("#arc0").hasClass("selected") &&
    $("#arc1").hasClass("selected") &&
    $("#arc2").hasClass("selected") &&
    $("#arc3").hasClass("selected") &&
    $("#arc4").hasClass("selected") &&
    $("#arc5").hasClass("selected") &&
    $("#arc6").hasClass("selected") &&
    $("#arc7").hasClass("selected") &&
    $("#arc8").hasClass("selected")
  ) {
    $(".arc").removeClass("selected");
    $(".image").removeClass("selected");
  } else {}
};

const handleNoClick = (d, i, n) => {
  if (!$("#arc0").hasClass("selected") &&
    !$("#arc1").hasClass("selected") &&
    !$("#arc2").hasClass("selected") &&
    !$("#arc3").hasClass("selected") &&
    !$("#arc4").hasClass("selected") &&
    !$("#arc5").hasClass("selected") &&
    !$("#arc6").hasClass("selected") &&
    !$("#arc7").hasClass("selected") &&
    !$("#arc8").hasClass("selected")
  ) {
    $(".arc").addClass("selected");
    $(".image").addClass("selected");
  } else {}
};

var h = 800
var w = 800
const arc = d3.arc();

var arcData = [{
    domain: "1",
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: h / 1.75,
    startAngle: (Math.PI * -20) / 180,
    endAngle: (Math.PI * 20) / 180,
  },
  {
    domain: " 2 ",
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: 300,
    startAngle: (Math.PI * 20) / 180,
    endAngle: (Math.PI * 60) / 180,
  },
  {
    domain: "3",
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: 280,
    startAngle: (Math.PI * 60) / 180,
    endAngle: (Math.PI * 100) / 180,
  },
  {
    domain: "4",
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: 260,
    startAngle: (Math.PI * 100) / 180,
    endAngle: (Math.PI * 140) / 180,
  },
  {
    domain: "5",
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: 240,
    startAngle: (Math.PI * 140) / 180,
    endAngle: (Math.PI * 180) / 180,
  },
  {
    domain: "6",
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: 220,
    startAngle: (Math.PI * 180) / 180,
    endAngle: (Math.PI * 220) / 180,
  },
  {
    domain: "7",
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: 200,
    startAngle: (Math.PI * 220) / 180,
    endAngle: (Math.PI * 260) / 180,
  },
  {
    domain: "8",
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: 150,
    startAngle: (Math.PI * 300) / 180,
    endAngle: (Math.PI * 340) / 180,
  },
  {
    domain: "9",
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: 100,
    startAngle: (Math.PI * 260) / 180,
    endAngle: (Math.PI * 300) / 180,
  },
];
// Order needs to be from JSON
var colorScale = d3
  .scaleOrdinal()
  .domain([
    "1",
    " 2 ",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "8",
    "9",
  ])
  .range([
    "#f7941e",
    "#233f92",
    "#14385c",
    "#007ac1",
    "#4c3b2d",
    "#94c83d",
    "#0000a0",
    "#440099",
    "#e7253d",
  ]);
const slices = arcData.map((d) => arc(d));

svg
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(slices)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("transform", "translate(325,550)")
  .attr("d", (d) => d)
  .attr("id", (d, i) => "arc" + i)
  .style("fill", (d, i) => colorScale(i))
  .style("z-index", 100)
  .style("opacity", 0.5)
  .attr("class", "arc selected")
  .attr('transform', 'scale(0,0)')
  .on("mouseover", handleMouseOver)
  .on("mouseout", handleMouseOut)
  .transition().transition()
  .delay(400)
  .duration(function(d, i) {
    return 70 * i
  })
  .attr('transform', 'scale(1,1)')
  .attr()
  .on("click", function(d, i) {
    handleClick();
    d3.select(this).classed(
      "selected",
      d3.select(this).classed("selected") ? false : true
    );
    d3.select("image#arc" + i).classed(
      "selected",
      d3.select(this).classed("selected") ? true : false
    );
    handleNoClick();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='radial-chart'></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue was because an element can have only one attribute at a time. In this case, you gave each path `transform="translate(325,550)"`, but then replaced it with `transform="scale(0, 0)"`.

Luckily, you can chain these transforms together: `transform="translate(325,550) scale(0, 0)"`, which applies them in order. After the animation, this becomes `transform="translate(325,550) scale(1, 1)"`

```js
var h = 800
var w = 800
const arc = d3.arc();

const svg = d3
  .select("#radial-chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);


const handleMouseOver = (d, i, n) => {
  svg.selectAll("path").transition().duration(300).style("opacity", 0.35);

  d3.select(n[i]).transition().duration(300).style("opacity", 0.35);
};

const handleMouseOut = (d, i, n) => {
  svg
    .selectAll("path")
    .transition()
    .duration(300)
    .style("opacity", 0.35)
    .style("stroke-width", 0);
};

const handleClick = (d, i, n) => {
  if (
    $("#arc0").hasClass("selected") &&
    $("#arc1").hasClass("selected") &&
    $("#arc2").hasClass("selected") &&
    $("#arc3").hasClass("selected") &&
    $("#arc4").hasClass("selected") &&
    $("#arc5").hasClass("selected") &&
    $("#arc6").hasClass("selected") &&
    $("#arc7").hasClass("selected") &&
    $("#arc8").hasClass("selected")
  ) {
    $(".arc").removeClass("selected");
    $(".image").removeClass("selected");
  } else {}
};

const handleNoClick = (d, i, n) => {
  if (!$("#arc0").hasClass("selected") &&
    !$("#arc1").hasClass("selected") &&
    !$("#arc2").hasClass("selected") &&
    !$("#arc3").hasClass("selected") &&
    !$("#arc4").hasClass("selected") &&
    !$("#arc5").hasClass("selected") &&
    !$("#arc6").hasClass("selected") &&
    !$("#arc7").hasClass("selected") &&
    !$("#arc8").hasClass("selected")
  ) {
    $(".arc").addClass("selected");
    $(".image").addClass("selected");
  } else {}
};

var arcData = [{
    domain: "1",
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: h / 1.75,
    startAngle: (Math.PI * -20) / 180,
    endAngle: (Math.PI * 20) / 180,
  },
  {
    domain: " 2 ",
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: 300,
    startAngle: (Math.PI * 20) / 180,
    endAngle: (Math.PI * 60) / 180,
  },
  {
    domain: "3",
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: 280,
    startAngle: (Math.PI * 60) / 180,
    endAngle: (Math.PI * 100) / 180,
  },
  {
    domain: "4",
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: 260,
    startAngle: (Math.PI * 100) / 180,
    endAngle: (Math.PI * 140) / 180,
  },
  {
    domain: "5",
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: 240,
    startAngle: (Math.PI * 140) / 180,
    endAngle: (Math.PI * 180) / 180,
  },
  {
    domain: "6",
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: 220,
    startAngle: (Math.PI * 180) / 180,
    endAngle: (Math.PI * 220) / 180,
  },
  {
    domain: "7",
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: 200,
    startAngle: (Math.PI * 220) / 180,
    endAngle: (Math.PI * 260) / 180,
  },
  {
    domain: "8",
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: 150,
    startAngle: (Math.PI * 300) / 180,
    endAngle: (Math.PI * 340) / 180,
  },
  {
    domain: "9",
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: 100,
    startAngle: (Math.PI * 260) / 180,
    endAngle: (Math.PI * 300) / 180,
  },
];
// Order needs to be from JSON
var colorScale = d3
  .scaleOrdinal()
  .domain([
    "1",
    " 2 ",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "8",
    "9",
  ])
  .range([
    "#f7941e",
    "#233f92",
    "#14385c",
    "#007ac1",
    "#4c3b2d",
    "#94c83d",
    "#0000a0",
    "#440099",
    "#e7253d",
  ]);
const slices = arcData.map((d) => arc(d));

svg
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(slices)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", (d) => d)
  .attr("id", (d, i) => "arc" + i)
  .style("fill", (d, i) => colorScale(i))
  .style("z-index", 100)
  .style("opacity", 0.5)
  .attr("class", "arc selected")
  .attr('transform', 'translate(325,550) scale(0,0)')
  .on("mouseover", handleMouseOver)
  .on("mouseout", handleMouseOut)
  .transition().transition()
  .delay(400)
  .duration(function(d, i) {
    return 70 * i
  })
  .attr('transform', 'translate(325,550) scale(1,1)')
  .on("click", function(d, i) {
    handleClick();
    d3.select(this).classed(
      "selected",
      d3.select(this).classed("selected") ? false : true
    );
    d3.select("image#arc" + i).classed(
      "selected",
      d3.select(this).classed("selected") ? true : false
    );
    handleNoClick();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='radial-chart'></div>
```